# IP address appears instead of hostname on LAN to network router

Tags: linux, networking, router, centos-6

In the CentOS 6 servers the hostname command displays the name, but in the "PC NAME" field in the Actiontech router it displays the IP address. How can I make sure the CentOS servers are communicating the actual hostname?

The hostname is being displayed correctly in the "PC NAME" field for a Mac Mini, and also a Raspberry Pi 2.

I should mention the IP addresses for CentOS are static. Does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

> I  should mention the IP addresses for CentOS are static. Does that matter?

Yes it does. DHCP clients communicate their name in the course of DHCP negotiation. In fact, the first two lines of /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf (on Debian, I do not know where that is on CentOS but it makes no difference) are:

```
  #send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
  send host-name = gethostname();
```

With a static IP configuration there is no need for such an exchange: the static machine already  has all the knowledge (address, network, mask, gateway, DNS servers) and it needs no exchange with the router.

Only Windows machines broadcast their machine name, which is most often, but not necessarily, the same as their hostname. If you have a Samba server on your CentOS machine, you can do the same.

The best solution, in my opinion, is setting up a *reserved address*: many routers allow you to choose a fixed IP address from within their subnet, to dish out only to a specific machine, identified by its MAC address. This is like DHCP, except the given machine is the only one, ever, that gets that IP address. But being like DHCP, the name of the pc is given to the router, and thus becomes resolvable by the local DNS server, if any.